# How to put an Expectation symbol in IEEE Transanctions format?

Tags: symbols, ieeetran

I have already tried

```
\mathbb{E}

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}
\end{equation}
```

and

```
$\mathbb{E}$
```

What exactly is the way to do it?

Comment: I already stumbled upon it.

Comment: And? Did it produce what you wanted? If not, please mention this fact in an edit to your question and also mention why the answer provided there doesn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Did you include the `amssymb` package?